# Is it possible to run Dianoga in an Azure Web App?

Tags: paas, dianoga

A very simple question I'm looking to get confirmed.

Can you run [Dianoga](https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga) module in `Sitecore` within an `Azure Web App` context?

My main concern is that it requires `.exe` files for compression as mentioned in this [question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5636/clarification-sitecore-dianoga-module).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used this for a while and can confirm that it works (up to SC 8.2). Furthermore, I just tested it and it still works with Sitecore 9 in PaaS.

Once installed, look for Dianoga informational messages in Application Insights after requesting your images. It should look somewhat like this:

[image]

If you refresh your image (bypassing the browser cache) once it's processed (i.e. after being requested once on the web site), you can compare sizes before and after. If you test with larger, unoptimized images, you should see some decent gains.

Notes:

- I've never used the SVG compression.
- I have not tested the nQuant method of PNG compression.
- The default PNGOptimizer requires a 64-bit application pool.